# Toggle Image Source on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a typical expand and collapse function to display/hide a div on image click.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="result_location">
    <h3>Heading Text here</h3>       
</div>
<div class="result_menu"></div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```js
$('#result_location').click(function() { 
    $('.result_menu').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

So there's going to be an image within the `#result_location` div, that alternates between a plus/minus when the `.result_menu` gets toggled.

Hope that kinda makes sense!

Comment: What Javascript/jQuery code do you have so far?

Comment: updated, so at the minute, the whole div acts as a toggle, where I just want an image to do the toggling, but for the image to alternate for when its open/closed.

Comment: Your markup is incomplete as well seeing as you mention toggling an image, but do not have any `<img>` tags. Unless you're wanting to toggle a background image set in CSS. If that's the case then we'd need to see your CSS.

Comment: What's the question here? All I see is an explanation of code.

Comment: dude please provide the css you are using.

Comment: As an aside, you can also have the plus and minus images as one image, and shift the background-position value of the div up and down. The bigger benefits of this are a simpler jQuery click method and one file to load instead of two, so the minus image wont be missing while it is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have wrote a fiddle for you.
Basically toggling the source will done the trick.

Here is the code

Html

```
<div class="msg_list">
    <p class="result_location">Heading Text here<img src="http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif"></img></p>
        <div class="result_menu">
            This <br/>
            is <br/>
            a <br/>
            Testing <br/>
            Content
        </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(".result_location").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".result_menu").slideToggle("slow");
})
.toggle( function() {
    $(this).children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/ExpandSign.gif");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("img").attr("src","http://prtlimages.cunamutual.com/ImageServer/Portal/B2B/CollapseSign.gif");
});
```

check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2UuW6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I read correctly, your "trigger" is `.result_menu`. Here is a JSFiddle that accomplishes what I think you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/trevanhetzel/P4N2c/

Essentially, we bind to the trigger element using `.on("click")` and then find the image to toggle and `.slideToggle` it. Pretty straightforward.

```
$(function () {
    $(".result_menu").on("click", function () {
       $("#result_location img").slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

You'll also want to `display: none` the image in the CSS.

Am I missing anything about your desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle a class on `#result_location` and then add the arrow image as a CSS background image for that selector. When clicked again the class would be removed, thus removing/changing the image.